# What should I do to use a specific font in my web app?

Tags: javascript, webpack, fonts

I am writing a Web App that should run either from the cloud and from an isolated LAN (e.g. without Internet access).

I am quite new to JavaScript and Webpack, but as I figured out I need to provide the source of OpenSans in different formats:

- open-sans-light.ttf
- open-sans-light.eot
- open-sans-light.woff
- open-sans-light.woff2

I managed to download OpenSans from https://fonts.google.com (only the `ttf` version though).

Then I put this in `_font.scss`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans Light';
  src: url('../fonts/open-sans-bold-light.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/open-sans-bold-light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/open-sans-bold-light.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/open-sans-bold-light.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/open-sans-bold-light.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do?

Comment: The snippet is correct, but you need the rest of fonts https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/open-sans?subsets=latin

Comment: Why are you bothering? Just load the font directly from Google Fonts. That's what the service is made for. `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @JeremyThille, the app should run without Internet :(

Comment: Ah right, sorry. Details :)

Comment: You can remove the first `src` attribute as it's repeated below, but other than that it's all good, assuming the files are in the specified folder.

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Thanks for this excellent link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the path for fonts it correct and use `font-family: 'OpenSans Light';` on elements you want to have that font and you are good to go.